# Bitbucket API - Using access_token

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to get the repo details, of our comany bitbucket cloud.
using the API:

```
curl --request GET \
   --url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
   --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

from
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-get

the problem is that every key/token I use, I get an error response of

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Access token expired."}}
```

I created an OAuth 2.0 key and secret and tried them both.

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <KEY>'
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <SECRET>'
```

I also tried App Password :

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <APP PASSWORD>'
```

also with SSH key:

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <SSH KEY>'
```

But I get the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you omit the 'Authorization: Bearer' header completely, and use an *app_password* instead. In fact, Atlassian recommends the use of app passwords, allowing you to completely bypass the need for an `access_token`.

See the [App passwords](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#app-passwords) section of the Authentication Methods docs page.

Here's how it works. (Notice that the 'Authorization: Bearer' header is absent in these examples.) If your workspace is **companyname**, your username is **prospero** , and the app password you created per the Atlassian documentation is **a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8**, then you can retrieve the list of repositories in this manner.

Curl:

```
curl -u prospero:a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8 https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/companyname
```

Python:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/companyname', auth=('prospero', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8'))
print(r.text)
print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4))
```

Of course, you will want to use more sophisticated code. These are just quick examples.